# A long sentence that begins with word "Using"

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence correct?

> Using data on A and B, I study X by doing Y.

My concern is that, the word "using" already states how "I study X", which might conflict with "by doing Y".

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe no, depending on how A and B relate to Y. At any rate, correct or not, if something concerns you, you can always reword. As well you should.

Comment: In the general presentation you've given us, at least, I don't see a problem necessarily.